# How to create a custom Facelets tag?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, custom-tags, tagfile

I am using JSF 2.0. I created custom JSTL tags with tagfiles and that were working fine in JSP. But I want to use custom JSTL tags in Facelets too. Is it possible to create tagfiles in Facelets or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726523/migrating-from-jsf1-2-to-jsf2-0-what-to-do-with-jstl

Comment: Thanks I have check that question as well but I have created custom jstl tags that is working fine in jsp but when I use that tag in faces by giving  "xmlns:ct="http://ve.customTag" namespace then its not working in faces. kindly tell that how to use my custom jstl tags in jsf

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> *I created custom JSTL tags with tagfiles and that were working fine in JSP.*

The phrase "custom JSTL tags" makes no sense. JSTL is *already* a taglib at its own. Read the introductory paragraphs of [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to learn what JSTL really is. You perhaps actually meant "[custom JSP tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html)". Of course they would not work in Facelets as that's a completely different view technology than JSP and actually the successor of the deprecated JSP. See also [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)

> *But I want to use custom JSTL tags in Facelets too*

The analogy of a "custom JSP tag" in Facelets is a "custom Facelets tag", or more commonly "Facelets tag file". It's rather simple, you can follow the same syntax as an include file.

`/WEB-INF/tags/some.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    Hello World
    ...
    <ui:insert /> <!-- This inserts tag body, if necessary. -->
</ui:composition>
```

and register it in `/WEB-INF/example.taglib.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <namespace>http://example.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>some</tag-name>
        <source>tags/some.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

which is in turn registered in `/WEB-INF/web.xml` as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/example.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

*(note that registration in `web.xml` is unnecessary when the `*.taglib.xml` file is in `/META-INF` folder of a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib`)*

and finally use it in your templates as follows:

```
<html ... xmlns:my="http://example.com/jsf/facelets">
...
<my:some />
```

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269)
- [Structure for multiple JSF projects with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320486/structure-for-multiple-jsf-projects-with-shared-code)