# How to make p:panel collapsible by clicking on header?

Tags: jquery, primefaces, toggle

I'm using **PrimeFaces 3.4** collapsible panels. The problem with actual solution is that panel is toggled via clicking in small button on the right. It is not very ergonomic and the user would expect the toggling via clicking anywhere on header.

This is what I want to implement: trigger the toggle via clicking on header and remove the toggle button. This is what I've written:

```
$('.ui-panel-titlebar').each(function(){
    var header = $(this);
    var widgetId = 'widget_' + header.attr('id').replace(/:/g, '_').replace(/_header$/, '');
    header.css('cursor', 'pointer');
    var toggler = header.find('a[id$=_toggler]');
    toggler.remove();
    header.click(function(){
        window[widgetId].toggle();
    });
});
```

But I don't like that solution, because first I'm guessing the JavaScript widget Id, and second, I'm removing the rendered toggle button from DOM tree and I would prefer it not to be rendered at all.

Is there a way to achieve the same effect in more elegant way without writing too many code (so, without rewriting the `p:panel`)? Using extensions based on same licence as PrimeFaces (commerce-friendly) is acceptable as solution.

Answer (score 5):

Since PrimeFaces 6.2, this behavior is supported via the new [`toggleableHeader`](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.2/core/primefaces-p/panel.html)-attribute:

```
<p:panel header="This is my header text"
         toggleable="true"
         toggleableHeader="true">
  The content of the panel.
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was unfortunately not able to find a PrimeFaces solution. I wrote a custom JQuery script which simulate click on the toggle button if the click on the title bar.

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-panel:has(.ui-panel-titlebar-icon) .ui-panel-titlebar", function(e) {
    console.log("click:");
    if (e.srcElement != null) { // avoid infinite loop
        $(this).find("a.ui-panel-titlebar-icon").click();
    }
});
```

Thanks to the `on`, this works also after any Ajax update. I think that should be easy to set this behaviour only to panels with a given class (e.g. `panel-header-click`).

I only tested the code on Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to have panels that optionally are togglable by clicking on the header, and also to have the icon at the left side of the panel. I chose to [create a custom tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag) to do so.

`my.taglib.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
                version="2.0">
  <namespace>http://my.com/jsf/facelets</namespace>
  <tag>
    <tag-name>togglePanel</tag-name>
    <source>tags/togglePanel.xhtml</source>
    <attribute>
      <name>header</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
      <name>collapsed</name>
      <required>false</required>
      <type>boolean</type>
    </attribute>
  </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

`togglePanel.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <c:set var="collapsed" value="#{not empty collapsed and collapsed}" />

  <p:panel toggleable="true" collapsed="#{collapsed}" class="myToggleable">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(this.parentNode.parentNode.id.replace('_header', '_toggler')).click()"><h:outputText
          value="#{header}"/></a>
    </f:facet>
    <ui:insert />
  </p:panel>

</ui:composition>
```

Style sheet:

```
.ui-panel.myToggleable .ui-panel-titlebar { 
  position: relative; padding: .5em 1em .3em 2.5em;
}
.ui-panel.myToggleable .ui-panel-title,
.ui-panel.myToggleable .ui-panel-title a {
  display: block; text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-panel.myToggleable .ui-panel-titlebar-icon,
.ui-panel.myToggleable .ui-panel-titlebar-icon:hover {
  position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; margin: 0;
}
```

Now you can use it like this in your XHTML files:

```
<my:togglePanel header="Header" collapsed="false">
  ...
</my:togglePanel>
```

You should add the following namespace though: `xmlns:my="http://my.com/jsf/facelets"`.

This has been tested using PrimeFaces 6.0.

Comment: popUp's me the message: **Warning: This page calls for XML namespaces http://my.com/jsf/facelets declared with prefix my but no taglibrary exists for that namespace.**

Comment: Please read the linked question "How to create a custom Facelets tag?"

Answer (score 1):

The [p:accordionPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf) is a collapsible panel which can be toggled by clicking anywhere on the header.

Comment: AccordionPanel is content switcher, so it's the completly different case than mine.

Answer (score 1):

In primefaces 5.2 is

```
$(document).on("click", ".ui-panel:has(.ui-panel-titlebar-icon) .ui-panel-titlebar", function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.className);
    if (e.target.className === "ui-panel-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"
            || e.target.className === "ui-panel-title"){
        $(this).find("a.ui-panel-titlebar-icon").click();
    }
});
```