# JSF: Get HTML element ID in which JSF code exists

Tags: html, jsf, jsf-2

I wanted to ask you all if there is a possibility to dynamically get the element ID in which JSF code exists.

What I mean by that is fx.:

```
    <p id="paragraph1" class="textToEdit">#{paragraphBean.getParagraphTextById("paragraph1")}</p>
```

In this line of code instead of me writing "paragraph1" in the JSF code I want it to be pulled from the `<p>` ID element.

Thanks in advance for all of your responses..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only possible on JSF components, not on plain HTML elements. JSF will push the "[current component](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-)" as `#{component}` in EL scope.

```
<h:someComponent id="foo">#{bean.foo(component.id)}</h:someComponent>
```

Your best bet is refactoring the boilerplate into a [custom tagfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag).

```
<my:p id="paragraph1" styleClass="textToEdit" />
```

Where `/WEB-INF/tags/p.xhtml` is implemented as below.

```
<p id="#{id}" class="#{styleClass}">#{paragraphBean.getParagraphTextById(id)}</p>
```