# Remove redundant attributes facelet tag files jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

According to this link:

[How to create a custom Facelets tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag)

I was able to create a facelet tag files.

A part of my CustomGraphicImage.xhtml file:

```
<h:graphicImage style="border: #{border}px solid #000000" height="#{height}" width="#{width}" alt="#{alt}" library="image" name="#{value}" />
```

My test.xhtml file:

```
<my:ImgPath border="1" value="loading_pt01.gif"></my:ImgPath>
```

The problem is that when view HTML source code, undefined attributes still appear. In the below example, undefined tags are `alt, height, width`.

```
<img src="/demo-project/javax.faces.resource/loading_pt01.gif.xhtml?ln=image" style="border: 1px solid #000000" alt height width>
```

How can I display only defined attributes?

I'm thinking about using `<c:if>` to decide to whether display the attributes or not but that seems too much work.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=jsf+conditionally+add+attributes

Comment: or check if they have a value and otherwise add '100%' in a conditional expression