# Library of Custom JSF Controls (custom design without affecting usage in backend)

Tags: jsf, look-and-feel, customising

I am trying to create a library of customised JSF controls, but the customisation pertains only to the design (look and feel and maybe simple interactions) not the functionality. I am not sure what the best way to do this as I am new to Java/JSF... I have tried creating a custom tag, but it seems that one has to pass all the attributes from the container custom tag to the inner tag to be able to read/write the values (which is a hassle unless I am missing some feature in JSF). Also not sure how this will affect event handling in the backend code, that is usually handled directly on a JSF native tag.

Is there a way to separate the design from the functionality/attributes/events?
The main goal is to create a nice textbox template where the default style is changed only in one place as opposed to going over pages where the control is used and adding/editing/removing classes...

### Example below:

The below represents a custom tag:

```
<pk:inputText id="txtBx" value="Default Text Here" />
```

This is used in a page. It is a styled version of the regular JSF control using Tailwind CSS:

```
<h:inputText></h:inputText>
```

I would like the backend developers to use it smoothly without affecting their functions

The custom tag implementation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:body>
      <ui:composition>
        <h:inputText styleClass="appearance-none block w-full md:w-1/3 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 border rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white" value = "#{value}" id = "#{id}">  
        </h:inputText>  
      </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thank you for the link. I am not sure how this answers my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Custom tags can also access attributes not explicit given as argument. `<ui:param`s previous defined, are accessible without passing as argument.