# PrimeFaces edit authority of InputText based on role

Tags: jsf, primefaces, user-roles

I want to set the modify authority of an `p:inputText` in PrimeFaces, but I want to this on Xhtml page (not in the managed bean). For example I can use "Rendered" attribute to hide the `p:inputText` for nonAdmin users. However, I want nonAdmin users to see the `p:inputText` but they should not change the value, just admins can change/delete/update the value. The admins should have modify authority, non admin users should just have read authority. Is there any attribute like `rendered`?

```html
<p:inputText rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('Admin')}"
             value="#{managedService.files.price}"/>
```

Note: I may do this on managed bean but I want to know whether it is possible on just xhtml page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set the `readonly` or `disabled` attributes of the `p:inputText`.

Or you could use the `p:inplace` component and disable it:

```html
<p:inplace disabled="#{not request.isUserInRole('Admin')}">
  <f:facet name="output">
    #{managedService.files.price}
  </f:facet>
  <f:facet name="input">
    <p:inputText value="#{managedService.files.price}"/>
  </f:facet>
</p:inplace>
```

If you are not "Admin", you can see the price, but not edit it.

But I would create a custom tag to keep your XHTML pages DRY and less verbose. See for example: [How to create a custom Facelets tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751624/how-to-create-a-custom-facelets-tag)